# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition"

Tags: tiles, dtd, struts-1

While starting the WAS 8.5 server by publishing my application, I'm getting the below error:

[3/17/16 14:29:50:216 IST] 0000004c Digester      E org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error Parse Error at line 99 column 169: Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition".
                                 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:281)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.parseXmlFile(I18nFactorySet.java:514)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.parseXmlFiles(I18nFactorySet.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.createDefaultFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:266)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.initFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:241)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.initFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.definition.ComponentDefinitionsFactoryWrapper.init(ComponentDefinitionsFactoryWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesUtilImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesUtil.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin.initDefinitionsFactory(TilesPlugin.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin.init(TilesPlugin.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomActionServlet.init(CustomActionServlet.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1366)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:623)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:589)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)

[3/17/16 14:29:50:218 IST] 0000004c Digester      E org.apache.commons.digester.Digester error Parse Error at line 108 column 171: Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition".
                                 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "controllerClass" must be declared for element type "definition".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1765)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:281)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.parseXmlFile(I18nFactorySet.java:514)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.parseXmlFiles(I18nFactorySet.java:449)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.createDefaultFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:266)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.initFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:241)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.xmlDefinition.I18nFactorySet.initFactory(I18nFactorySet.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.definition.ComponentDefinitionsFactoryWrapper.init(ComponentDefinitionsFactoryWrapper.java:105)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesUtilImpl.java:175)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesUtil.java:182)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin.initDefinitionsFactory(TilesPlugin.java:226)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin.init(TilesPlugin.java:141)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModulePlugIns(ActionServlet.java:871)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:359)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:161)
    at com.s1.arch.ui.action.CustomActionServlet.init(CustomActionServlet.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:342)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1366)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:623)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:589)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:425)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1177)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2195)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5477)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5603)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2200)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:435)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:378)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:126)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:984)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1865)

Could some one please help.

Comment: Corresponding tiles file entries are below:
Line-99:<definition name="sb_prefs_passwdParent.page" extends="twoColBaseLayout.page" controllerClass="com.s1.web.bankcommon.security.changePassword.PasswordChangeController">

Line-108:<definition name="sb_logon_passwdParent.page" extends="exteriorBaseLayout.page" controllerClass="com.s1.web.bankcommon.security.changePassword.PasswordChangeController">

Header of the file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration//EN"   "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/tiles-config.dtd">

Comment: Edit the question instead of adding details in a comment.

Comment: Did that intially. But somehow,those are not visible even though i copied. So, added a new comment with details.

Comment: Which part of the sentence "Attribute A must be declared for element E" are you having trouble understanding?